# Android FragmentBreadCrumbs deprecated? Why?

Tags: android, breadcrumbs

I have a question about creating breadcrumbs in an Android application. The android.app.FragmentBreadCrumbs class was deprecated in API Level 21. I can't seem to find another way to implement breadcrumb links in an Android application.

Does anyone know of another method?

Also if anyone knows why the android.app.FragmentBreadCrumbs class was deprecated, that might be helpful. Is it the case that using a breadcrumb scheme for Android apps is frowned upon (maybe because they can get quite long)?

Any answers or opinions on this subject would be appreciated. 
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

> Does anyone know of another method?

You could look at [the source code to `FragmentBreadCrumbs`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/app/FragmentBreadCrumbs.java) and use it to either roll your own, or at least fork and maintain your own copy of theirs. Outside of processing the layout XML attributes (always a pain...), I'm not seeing anything obvious that can only work in the framework due to accessing stuff that's not in the Android SDK.

At the end of the day, it's just a custom `View` that allows navigating through the `BackStackEntry` chain.

> why the android.app.FragmentBreadCrumbs class was deprecated

It probably didn't fit Material Design. And you're the first person I've ever heard of using it.

Answer (score 2):

In google drive for tablet (material design) I can see the breadcrumb.

Comment: This is no answer to the question. This is a comment to CommonsWare at best.